# Evaluate $\int\frac{e^x}{x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $\int\frac{e^x}{x}\ dx$

I was working on this problem. I took the Taylor Series of $e^x$ - $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and divided it by $x$ - getting: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$.

I then took the integral of that: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{(n)n!}$.

I thought this was the correct answer. But, the book took out a $\frac1x$ from the sum before integrating ($\frac1x$ is the first term and so they just bumped the index up). They then integrated it separately getting an answer of: $\ln\,|x|+ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{(n)n!} +C$
Did they do this because in my attempt at $n=0$ the series doesn't work? Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Yes, you cannot have $0$ in the denominator.

Comment: $\int \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n-1}}{n!} \ dx.$  The $\frac {x^{-1}}{0!}$ term integrates differently from the rest of the terms of the series, and it definitely does not equal $\frac {x^0}{0}$

Answer (score 2):

When $n=0$ the integral in your sum is $\int \frac{x^{-1}}{0!} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln|x|$. The power rule $\int x^k \, dx = \frac{1}{n} x^{k+1}$ only works when $k \ne -1$.